# How does the Poincare series of a Hopf algebra quotient $A/B$ relate to the Poincare series of $A$ and $B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

**Background:**

Given $\mathbb{F}_2$-graded Hopf algebra $A$, define as $h_A(d) := \dim A_d$ (where the dimension is as a $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space), where $A_d$ is the degree $d$ component of $A$. The Poincare series $P_A(t)$ is then $\sum_{t = 0}^\infty h_A(d)t^d$.

---

Then, given $P_A(t)$ and $P_B(t)$, how do these relate to $P_{A//B}(t)$, where $A//B = A \otimes_B \mathbb{F}_2$?

It seems that $P_{A/B}(t)$ would be $P_A(t) - P_B(t)$ or $P_A(t)/P_B(t)$. However, neither seem to be true. Indeed, quotienting by $B$ invokes lots of relations which don't seem to be adequately cancelled by just subtracting.

Comment: What is $B$ ? A subalgebra of $A$? An $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra over which $B$ is an algebra?

Comment: $B$ is a sub-algebra of $A$.

Comment: I'm surprised that $P_{A}(t) / P_{B}(t)$ isn't true, as I would expect that $A//B \otimes _{\mathbb{F}_{2}} B$ as vector spaces, similarly how given a short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 0$ of groups we have that $G \simeq K \times H$ as sets. The proof proceeds by choosing a section of $H \rightarrow G$, which is only a map of sets, and then looking at the map $H \times K \rightarrow G \times G \rightarrow G$. Do you have any idea what goes wrong in the case of Hopf algebras..?